# .htaccess, Redirect doesn't work, RedirectMatch does

Tags: .htaccess

I've run into a situation I've never encountered before. We just moved a site between hosts and on the new host RedirectPermanent and Redirect commands in the .htaccess file seem to be ignored, but RedirectMatch is honored.

For example:

```
RedirectMatch       /product/C15        http://example.com/topic/category/displays
```

This works

```
RedirectPermanent   /product/C534       http://example.com/topic/tag/TVs
```

This doesn't work. I've also tried

```
Redirect 301        /product/C534       http://example.com/topic/tag/TVs
```

Neither of these work. I've checked and it isn't related to the source (if I switch RedirectMatch and RedirectPermanent, the link with RedirectMatch always works, the other always fails.)

For the rules that don't work, I just end up at 
example.com/index.php/product/C15 (for example). It's like apache doesn't acknowledge the RedirectPermanent rule at all

I do have some mod rewrite rules further down in htaccess to remove index.php, but I tried starting with a blank .htaccess and just 1 RedirectPermanent rule and it still failed. Apache error logs show nothing, access logs just show these urls going to a 404.

I'm on a hosted account so that's about as deep as I can go. We have at least a dozen different accounts with the same host and .htaccess works as expected on all the others.

Any thoughts? I've pushed this to the ISP but their policy is that they don't offer support on .htaccess issues, but to me it kind of feels like it's an apache config issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to turn on the rewrite log. To turn it on, try these lines in your apache main config or current virtual host file (not in .htaccess):

```
LogLevel alert rewrite:trace6
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to request that the ISP do this since I don't have access.